# Checking if String is empty or only white spaces

Tags: javascript

I have simple function handling a DOM event (input field from HTML document) that should proceed only if the value is not empty (nothing typed in the field) or only white space (user spamming space bar). How do I check both these with if-block of code?

Comment: `s.trim().length === 0 ? ... : ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `trim()`

check this out -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Usage example:

`if(string.trim().length === 0) {
//code here
}`

Comment: @JustAnotherDoomer does it answer your question ?

Answer (score -2):

Check out the [npm package "is-blank"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-blank). This should do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Sounds like an overkill to me